# dealing with those responses before target offset in a priming experiment

Tags: psycholinguistics

We conducted a priming lexical decision experiment, and the response time was calculated from the target onset. However when we cleaned the data, we found that some responses were given before the target offset, thus, my question is: how should we deal with these data (to delete them, or delete those response time less than 200ms, or just take them as valid data)?  Since we use Chinese words as targets, so it has different contours, which produced different durations, with falling tone about 300ms and the others about 400-600 ms.so one more question: should we use a 200 ms cut-off from the target onset or offset?

Any advice is appreciated!

Comment: What was the total time span in which the target was presented? How reliable the response is depends on how long after the *onset* it occured; the time relative to the offset is not very informative without knowing how long the target was presented before its offset.